# Is there a simpler approach to this application of Dominated Convergence?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

For a measure theory class, I'm trying to evaluate:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^\infty_1\frac 1 {nx} e^{-x/n}\ \text d\lambda$$

Obviously I want to try and move the limit through the integral and conclude that the limit is $0$, so I need to either show this sequence of functions is increasing (monotone convergence), or dominate it (dominated convergence). I decided to try and dominate it, but my method feels a bit roundabout.

Fix $x$ and view $\frac 1 {nx} e^{-x/n}$ as a function in $n$. The derivative is:

$$e^{-x/n}\left(\frac 1 {n^3} - \frac 1 {xn^2} \right)$$

It's now easy to show that this has a single global maximum at $n=x$. Therefore I can conclude (I think) that $\frac 1 {e x^2}$ is greater than each of the integrands and thus apply LDC.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Nice argument! Your computation also shows that the convergence is not monotone in $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^\infty_1\frac 1 {nx} e^{-x/n}\ \text dx
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int^1_{0}\frac 1 {nu} e^{-1/nu}\ \text du
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\int^n_{0}\frac 1 {v} e^{-1/v}\ \text dv
$$

Now use the fact that if $f\sim g>0$ then
$$
\int_0^\infty f = \infty \implies \int_0^n f \sim \int_0^n g
$$

Comment: I can't quite follow the substitutions yet, but I think this is definitely how we were intended to do it.

Comment: the first one is $u = 1/x$. The second one is $v = nu$.

Comment: You have lost an $n$, $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{nu}\exp \left(-\frac{1}{nu}\right)\,du = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n \frac{1}{v} e^{-1/v}\,dv.$$ And you need that factor, since $\int_0^n \frac{1}{v} e^{-1/v}\,dv \sim \log n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks buddy!